# Refresh class every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using $.get to get results from php and update a class `.actions`. What I would like to do is call this every 5 seconds to update `.actions` with latest results. Is there a way to do this in jquery. Thanks

js

```
$.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/destroy/refreshBox.php?dstrcount=' + 'Actions', function(data) { 
$(".actions").text(data);
});
```

Comment: I think best way to do this is with setInterval.

Comment: Don't use AJAX polling for this. I know there will be people telling you to use `setInterval`, but it's a bad idea for a variety of reasons. I'd strongly suggest you look in to using WebSockets or Server Sent Events if you want to keep the UI in close sync with server-side data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is totally right ... consider his answer

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you have example of how to use Server Sent Events. Thanks

Comment: Sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events. They even have a link to a github repo with an example PHP project

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for link. Will read up on it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**setInterval()**](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setInterval.html)

like this

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.get('/domain/admin/requests/boxes/destroy/refreshBox.php?dstrcount=' + 'Actions', function(data) {
    $(".actions").text(data);
  });
}, 5000);
```

See an example on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvaw7rxr/534/

Comment: One question i have. Does this put strain on the server using setInterval. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 yes it does. You're multiplying all your requests per user. This is why AJAX polling isn't a good solution

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan many thanks rory